# exifprobe: An iPhone sent an image it just took to another iPhone. Can the received image be mined for GPS data with exifprobe?

Tags: iphone, gps, metadata, image-uploading, exiftool

Here is my new idea. Someone stole my iPhone, but they are apparently still using it because they called me a couple days later after having it be stolen. Can I convince the thief to send me a photo and get his coordinates from the metadata by using exifprobe? I'm thinking I can convince the thief to send a photo of the moon by saying something like "How has it been, [myname]. It's been a while. The moon looks so nice from over here, you should send me a photo of what it looks like on your side. How are the kids?"

---

Also, the friend I would be using to ask the thief to take a picture would be someone on the other side of the planet, so that person would have to send the image to me for processing, but I think that uploading the image strips the metadata sometimes.

Comment: "One possible reason, according to top law enforcement officials, is that phone companies want to protect their profits from selling phone insurance. A service that could deter thieves may undercut that revenue, they said."

Answer (score 0):

If you can get them to send a newly-taken photo, and that photo contains the appropriate metadata (it is an option to disable location information), then yes, you should be able to get it from the Exif data.

Note that you'll have to convince them to take a new picture and send it to you. Any old pictures, like ones that you took, would only tell you where you took the picture, not where your phone is now.

Comment: Yeah, I know. You got any clever ideas as to how to make a thief send a photo to an old friend in the messages of their stolen phone?

Comment: Do received phone calls have gps data?